# Can I access my ID Token from an AuthenticationStateProvider in my Blazor client?

Tags: authentication, blazor, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to access the ID Token provided by Azure AD. I really need to get access to the signature and all of the claims.

I can easily access the AuthenticationStateProvider and then get the User from that. The User property has all of the claims in it, but that seems to be all. I cannot figure out how to get access to the rest of the ID Token.

Here is the code I'm using in the code behind on my blazor page:

```
[Inject]
AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationState { get; set; }

public async Task<string> GetIDTokenAsync()
{
    var authState = await authenticationState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

    return string.Join(", ", authState.User.Claims.ToList());
}
```

I'm just returning the list as a string to see what data I'm getting.

Additionally, my bootstrap looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
        });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

After I open the website I log in using the RemoteAuthenticatorView component. I need to access the ID Token after logging in. Also I just want to clarify that I am not looking for the access token. I do not ask for any scopes, and therefore there is no access token. My goal here is to get the ID Token and pass it to my API where the API can verify the ID Token and then issue it's own access token.